# Trading error 400, what's the problem?

Tags: java-sdk

I receive an HTTP 400 error from the `/transactions` endpoint on public Horizon when running this code:

```
try {
    Network.usePublicNetwork();
    Server server = new Server("https://horizon.stellar.org");
    KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(CoinConfig.XLM_SECRET);
    KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId(accountsId);
    server.accounts().account(destination); 
    AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source);
    Transaction.Builder builder = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount);
    builder.addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), money).build());
    builder.addMemo(Memo.text(label));
    Transaction transaction = builder.build();
    transaction.sign(source);
    SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
    String hash = "";
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        hash = response.getHash();
    }
    System.out.println(hash);
    return hash;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ErrorException("Xlm Transaction Failure！", e);
}
```

Submission return:Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions}

Comment: Please copy & paste the stack trace or full error details.

Comment: All details are in the response body of horizon. You should check it first.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run a modified version of your code successfully on testnet:

```
Network.useTestNetwork();
Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/");
KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed("SBKL5C3CZ5OURFFSAVTVFFGDPLXPOBIAM2IHETXMERNUG3U5VHH34HWA");
KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GD2VTA6Y3REXSC4NTWEICM3I3WNFAP5DKEJRQDMW4BLGKFWVDIBTPWND");
server.accounts().account(destination);
AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source);
Transaction.Builder builder = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount);
builder.addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), "100").build());
builder.addMemo(Memo.text("SomeMemo"));
Transaction transaction = builder.build();
transaction.sign(source);
SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
String hash = "";
if (response.isSuccess()) {
    hash = response.getHash();
}
System.out.println(hash);
```

It's difficult to know what your issue is without seeing the error message in full.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception such as in

```
try {
  SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
  System.out.println("Success!");
  System.out.println(response);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

(Code from https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html)

An error 400 means horizon is not accepting your transaction for whatever reason. The exception message should contains details about why the transaction has been rejected.

Comment: This will provide even less information that what they'll get by throwing `ErrorException`.

Comment: Well I don't know about Java but in JavaScript the horizon response contains fields that give more details.

Comment: No worries. OP's code will throw the exception, causing the message, full stack trace and any chained exceptions to be printed to stderr